# I need help getting a variable from a function to alter a class attribute in the main()

Tags: python

This is my program.  [code inlined:]

```
import pygame, sys
import random

class Player1:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, points):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.points = points

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstName, self.lastName)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.points

    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            self.points += other
            return Person(points)

        except AttributeError:
            print "error"
            raw_input


class Player2:
    def __init__(self, firstName2, lastName2, points2):
        self.firstName2 = firstName2
        self.lastName2 = lastName2
        self.points2 = points2

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstName2, self.lastName2)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.points2

    def __add__(self, other):
        try:
            self.points += other
            return Person(points)

        except AttributeError:
            print "error"
            raw_input

def rollDie(sides):
    r = random.randint(1,sides)
    return r

def takeTurn(player):
    points = int(player)
    if int(player) < 100:
        keepRolling = 1
        print
        raw_input("%s <press enter to begin turn>" % (player))
        while keepRolling == 1:
            r = rollDie(6)
            print "%s rolled a " % (player) + str(r)
            print
            if r == 1:
                points = str(int(player))
                print "%s your points are now " % (player) + `points` + " because you rolled a 1." 
                keepRolling = 0
                print "Turn over"
                print
            else:
                points += r
                print "%s your points are now " % (player) + `points` 
                kR = input("Keep rolling?(0=no 1=yes): ")
                if kR == 1:
                    print
                    keepRolling = 1
                else:
                    keepRolling = 0
                    print "%s your points are now " % (player) + `points` 
                    print "turn over"
                    print


    else:
        print
        print "Congradulations %s you have won the Game of Thrones..... I mean pig. Yeah, pig." % (player)
        print
        raw_input("%s, press any key to exit the game.........") % (player)
        sys.exit()

    return points


def intro():
    print "This is the game of pig."
    print
    print "Each player has to roll a six-sided die"
    print "until they get a 1, reach 100, or want to stop."
    print "If they roll a 1, they get nothing."
    print "When prompted, press 1 to roll, 2 to skip."



def main():

    player11 = raw_input("What is Player 1's first name? -> ")
    player12 = raw_input("Last name? -> ")
    player21 = raw_input("Player 2's first name? -> ")
    player22 = raw_input("Last name? -> ")
    desiredT = input("How many turns do you want? ")

    player1 = Player1(player11, player12, 0) #I need the point from take turn to change these zeros
    player2 = Player2(player21, player22, 0)

    def correctInfo():
        verify = raw_input("Is this info correct? Player 1 is %s: Player2 is %s? [y,n] -> " % (player1, player2))
        if verify == "y":
               print

        elif verify == "n":
                print
                print
                main()

        else: 
            print "Not a valid input"
            print
            correctInfo()

    def turns(t):
        for i in range(t):
            takeTurn(player1) #how do I get the point from here to change the class?
            takeTurn(player2)
        if int(player1) > int(player2):
            print
            print "%s has won with %s points." % (player1, int(player1))
            print

        else:
            print
            print "%s has won with %s points." % (player2, int(player2))
            print
        raw_input("press any key to exit.............")

    correctInfo()
    intro()
    turns(desiredT)


main()
```

There are comments in the relevant areas. I just need to figure out how to get the

```
return points
```

at the end of takeTurn() to alter

```
player1 = Player1(firstName, lastName, 0)
```

in main() the zero is what needs to change

Comment: please post your code on codepad or something similar where we dont need to download it..

Comment: Or, you know, put the code **here**?

Comment: I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Besides missing the whole point of why and when to use classes, there are a number of issues with your code.

You only need **one player class** if they are going to share *all* functionality.

```
player1 = player(player11, player12, 0) # These instances,
player2 = player(player21, player22, 0) # use the same class.
```

Change this and everything you have should still work fine.

You want to construct a player with points from a turn the player needs to participate in? Your logic is wrong here.

If you want to change the players points, do it **in the TakeTurn()** function. You already have access to the player object here.

```
TakeTurn(player):
    # Instead of return points
    player.points = points
```

Comment: Thank you ^ I am a complete novice, so it is appreciated.